# Evaluate untrimmed mean in R

Tags: r

I was using the `mean()` in base package and wanted to calculate untrimmed mean which wasn't being evaluated even after putting `trim = 0` . The code in which i was implementing the above is :-

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory,pollutant,id = 1:332){
    m = vector("numeric")
    for(i in id){
            #paste() is used to concatenate r strings. 
            if(i < 10){
                    table <- read.csv(paste(directory ,"/","00",i,".csv",sep = ""))
            }
            else if(i>=10 && i<=99){
                    table <- read.csv(paste(directory ,"/","0",i,".csv",sep = ""))
            }
            else{
                    table <- read.csv(paste(directory ,"/",i,".csv",sep = ""))
            }
            table <- table[,pollutant]
            m <- c(m,mean(table,na.rm = TRUE)) 
            print(m)
    }
    mean(m)
```

}

Please help me with the untrimmed mean i could easily write my own function but i would really prefer if there is a tweak or other function for this. Thanks in advance !....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mean()` function has the `trim` parameter and its default is 0. So using `mean(sample)` will give you the untrimmed mean.

Analyzing your function, you are reading several csv, calculating their mean. Then you are storing this value in a vector and in the end you calculate the mean of these means.

*This value is not the mean of all the csv together*, unless they all have the same number of elements. For example the mean of {1,2,3,4,5} is 3, but if you separate this into two groups: {1,2} and {3,4,5} their mean is 1.5 and 4. The mean of {1.5, 4} is 2.75 (not 3).